# Search animated pics with Google

Tags: google-search, google-image-search, animations

Is there a way to search for **animated** GIFs or PNGs with Google? (Not static GIF or PNG files, but *animated* files.) I’ve tried with *[apng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG)* but Google does not recognize that filetype and trims it.

Comment: Have you tried the "intitle.index.of (filetype:gif or filetype:png or one of the supported formats Here) google search that will find enough to keep you busy for awhile

Answer (score 2):

In Germany you can do it like this ("Animiert" means "animated"):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [advanced image search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search?hl=en) and select the file type from options.

Comment: this is the same just typing filetype:gif or filetype:png or one of the supported formats

Comment: yes it is, and you still can't find anything similar to what you look for?

Comment: it`s about ANIMATED pictures

Comment: I know what it's about. Google only supports specific formats, gif is one of them and most of the gifs are animated. The closest you can get to animated pngs via Google is to type "<your keyword> animated png or apng" If you still can't find anything related then you might search for animated gif/png galleries and try your chance there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing ['*.gif'](http://www.google.com/images?q=%2a.gif&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=899) in the search bar (I've found some animated gifs this way)

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Yes we know that, so basically the answer is no, Google can't search for animated GIFs.