# How to narrow Google Image Search to only include specific file type

Tags: google-search, google-image-search, search-operators

I want to narrow a Google Image Search to only include a specific file type.

In my specific case, I'm interested only in .gifs.

- Including the search term ".gif" does not effectively or consistently limit (or include) all .gifs in my search
- .gif is not a supported file type for [Google search indexing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287)

Is there a way to effectively do this?

Comment: Well , this question is very similar, (might help you:)[https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11695/search-animated-pics-with-google]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like including `filetype:gif` in the search adds a new "search tool" option to limit the results by filetype. (The menu also includes JPG, SVG, ICO, PNG, and several others.)

(The "Google search indexing" support page you link to only lets you know what files the Googlebot can look in to index the text. Images are parsed with machine-learning.)

In any event, using `filetype:gif` seems to only return GIF files.

Alternatively, you can also use `inurl:.gif`, which will look at the actual URL to see if the string is contained. It works pretty well, but will likely be subject to false positives. (Something like `http://www.example.com/images/catdog.gif.txt`.)

Comment: Ooo that "hidden" search tool is SUPER useful! (How did I never notice the `Tools` button in google image searches before??).  Also, It turns out that I *had* tried `filetype:gif` but erroneously assumed since it produced no results that using indexing for gifs didn't work. Turns out, google just couldn't find any gifs of my search term :p oops! Thanks for your quick and useful answer, @ale!

Answer (score -2):

Use the `Tools` or add `typefile:gif` at the end of your search.